# Do I need to have a sublicence from LMI for this?

Tags: linux, distributions

I need a sublicence from LMI in order to make a Linux distro? I am not going to use the "Linux" name, but it will use the Linux kernel, and in its website, I will say that it is based on "GNU/Linux". For this, do I need a sublicence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably. Their [website](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/programs/legal/trademark/fair-use) explains the few exceptions.

Note that a sublicense is free, and that if you're trying to produce a Linux distribution, there's hardly any reason for them to refuse it.